# How to disable Python RQ job's SyntaxWarning?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

Trying to avoid having [RQ](http://python-rq.org) display a warning message (to console) about using the `meta` dictionary for arbitrary property usage.  We are using it as is specified, and the warning continues to display.

**The warning displayed is as follows:**

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/job.py:381: SyntaxWarning: Getting custom properties from the job instance directly will be unsupported as of RQ 0.4. Please use the meta dict to store all custom variables.  So instead of this:

 job.foo

Use this:

 job.meta['foo']

SyntaxWarning)
```

Basically, it is pretty annoying because it interferes with normal debugging activities.

Any ideas on how to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `warnings` module's [simplefilter method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings). Requires use of a context manager. Code example copied wholesale from the linked section:

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Further arguments to `simplefilter` allow you to filter just the warnings you're getting from the specific place in the code you know about-- probably a good idea so other, new warnings that arise later won't be obscured.